# JS code works on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web page where it should detect me when the user closes the browser window with the X button, I managed to do it with JS, everything fine in all browsers, I used a condition so that in Firefox another code would execute me, this For compatibility, when uploading it to my server, it doesn't work for me in Firefox, it doesn't detect the event, it only detects me if I have another window open. Does anyone know what the problem is with this?

This is my code:

```
if (es_firefox) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var validNavigations = false;
        // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh (includes normal refresh)
        $(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                validNavigations = true;
            }
        });
        $("a").bind("click", function () {
            validNavigations = true;
        });
        $("form").bind("submit", function () {
            validNavigations = true;
        });
        $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function () {
            validNavigations = true;
        });
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
                validNavigations = true;
            }
        });
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 65 + 17 && e.ctrlKey) {
                validNavigations = true;

            }
        });


        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.key == "F5") {
                validNavigations = true;
            } else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "W" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
                validNavigations = true;
            } else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "R" && prevKey == "CONTROL") {
                validNavigations = true;
            } else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "F4" && (prevKey == "CONTROL" || prevKey == "CONTROL")) {
                validNavigations = true;
            }
        });

        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            if (!validNavigations) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'logout.php'
                });
            }

        };
    });
}
```

Comment: This is all client-side, so it's pretty unlikely that the server has anything to do with differences in behavior. Where does the value of **es_firefox** come from?

Comment: Use DOM instead of the jq

Comment: The variable es_firefox, is to detect which browser the user opened, if it opened in Chrome it executes another code, if it opened in Firefox it executes the code that was established, this due to compatibility problems. @DonR

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the DOM instead of jquery?@HamitYILDIRIM